# What is the fix for 'No p gain specified for pid. Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/back_right_wheel_joint ' ros melodic?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using gazebo_ros_control package from ROS melodic. I am geting error like

```
[ERROR] [1528754765.222507207, 9.660000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/back_right_wheel_joint
```

I believe I may need to change something in yaml file but I am quite not sure what do I need to change. Can somebody please point me out?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293830/what-is-the-fix-for-%27no-p-gain-specified-for-pid.--namespace:-/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/back_right_wheel_joint-%27-ros-melodic?/) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2018-06-11

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZNJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40353/znj/) on 2019-05-18**:
gazbo_ros_control package not working with my simulated mobile robot I have the following output when launch the gazebo simulator
No p gain specified for pid.gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/left_whee and also for the right_wheel
where I can modify the P gain
I did follow the tutorials for make a config and a launch files but no nothing remove that error and it cause a leak of movement during the test in Rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same question. The PID parameters are optional if you are using gazebo_ros_control. The error comes because when initializing RobotHWSim, the robot_ros_control tries to load the pid_gains. The source code and corresponding comments are [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/e42cc26a473733b05abc648181a6de1286105ed6/gazebo_ros_control/src/default_robot_hw_sim.cpp#L218).

Basically, if pid parameters were found, gazebo_ros_control will use pid controllers in ROS to control the joints (velocity or position) by effort. Otherwise, the joints will be controlled with gazebo methods.

---

Originally posted by [skyofyao@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/40266/skyofyao@gmail.com/) with karma: 171 on 2019-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-02-28**:
This answer seems correct to me. I'd also add that the ERROR from OP is not really an error. It's a sign that you aren't using PID controllers to control the joints (because you didn't specify `pid_gains`). I'm not sure about the decision to print ERRORS every time someone uses a non-PID controller

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2019-02-28**:
The commit that added the printouts is [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/pull/637/commits/2d796d78afbe703a6ac7a84959d953801bae0c6f). I think the choice to add these error messages stemmed from [a different bug](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/612)

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2019-03-07**:
That is right. After a long investigation, I did think that it is not an error but developers changed codes in ROS Melodic. Previous versions had bugs so the way I was using PID controls in Yaml would actually not do anything specific.  @sapan mentions the correct way to include PID values.

**Comment by [Withered_Shadow](https://answers.ros.org/users/41650/withered_shadow/) on 2019-05-20**:
Thanks, the format specified got it working. One last thing. What happens if I ignore this error. Does my bot still work as expected. Also why is it that the format in which I have specified works in another system where I installed ROS long back. Was there any official changes I missed. And lastly what are the Gazebo default PID parameters?

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2019-05-25**:
In my case, if I don't specify PID values, my bot still works, however, you will have to look at gazebo ros control source code to understand what exactly they do. It is better not to put any PID in the yaml file rather than putting the wrong value. To find suitable PID values use http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials. However, this is not easy especially when systems are coupled. This is really a hard problem to find a PID  value. I am going to write a custom control for my work which eventually won't use gazebo ros control.

**Comment by [LR](https://answers.ros.org/users/60755/lr/) on 2020-10-13**:
so,how to solve the error???

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like you configured a Joint (`back_right_wheel_joint`) to be controlled using, e.g. a `JointPositionController`. Obviously, you Need to specify the respective PID-Gains.

Check out [the tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control#Createa.yamlconfigfile). There it is described how the yaml file looks.

For more Debugging help, please provide us with the respective Launch and configuration files.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-05-20**:
unmarking this as correct since the other answers below are much more relevant by now...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5468/gazebo_ros_pkgs-no-p-gain-specified-for-pid-in-positionjointinterface/
Adding pid gains in following format worked for me.

```
/gazebo_ros_control:   
  pid_gains:
    shoulder_pan_joint:
      p: 100.0
      i: 0.01 
      d: 10.0
```

---

Originally posted by [sapan](https://answers.ros.org/users/27831/sapan/) with karma: 171 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohan_pannirselvam](https://answers.ros.org/users/54452/mohan_pannirselvam/) on 2020-05-05**:
hai . I am new to ROS. where can i find this yaml file? what command should i press on the terminal so that i can find and edit the file?

**Comment by [utkarsh singh](https://answers.ros.org/users/53509/utkarsh-singh/) on 2020-06-11**:
you have to create this .yaml file inside your config folder to use Controller in order to control a robot joints

**Comment by [jaiswalharsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/56717/jaiswalharsh/) on 2020-07-17**:
How to add these pid values if you have more than one joint? Should i just add different joint names and values below it?

**Comment by [KavitShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/60181/kavitshah/) on 2020-09-28**:
If you have more than one joints, you can do as follows:

gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains:
r_wheel_joint: {p: 1.0, i: 0.0, d: 1.0}
l_wheel_joint: {p: 1.0, i: 0.0, d: 1.0}

## more joint

**Comment by [KavitShah](https://answers.ros.org/users/60181/kavitshah/) on 2020-09-28**:
https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/397#issuecomment-699775702
You can follow this link to check about how to add params for multiple joints

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-28**:
For `velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController`, you don't need PID gains at all since it is a forward controller. Gazebo developers need to address this issue. There is no need for even warning.